# Making batch file with file check on multiple servers

Tags: batch-file

Greetings to everyone!

My chief has tasked me with making of batch file for checking a file existense on multiple servers. The task is to check file existence on network share (the path to share is "universal", the only difference is the name of server) - \servername\share\tools.

On my thoughts it looks like

```
@echo off
@echo %time%
FOR %%G IN (server1,server2,server3) DO (
    :test
    if exist "\\%%G\share\Tools\test1.txt" goto end
    timeout /T 1
    goto test
    :end
    @echo %time%
)
```

But asking something about 50 servers makes my brain to collapse - it takes (based on the %time% output) something about 0,02-0,1 seconds. It's unreal because these servers are from branch offices.

Where can be my error and how should I correct my script?

And another question is - how can mark time of beginning and ending for each server in my list? What output command should I give?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you cannot use `goto` inside `for`.It breaks brackets context.

Answer (score 0):

Try some of these:

```
@echo off

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set retries_limit=10
FOR %%G IN (server1,server2,server3) DO (
    echo testing %%G
    @echo %time% 
    for /l %%l in (1,1,%retries_limit%) do (
        set "flag="
        if exist "\\%%G\share\Tools\test1.txt" (
            set "flag=1"
        )
        timeout /T 1
    )
    if defined flag echo %%G is ok else echo something wrong with %%G
    @echo %time% end of %%G testing
)
endlocal
```

~

```
@echo off

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set retries_limit=10
FOR %%F "usebackq delims=" IN ("serverlist.txt") DO (
    echo testing %%G
    @echo %time% 
    for /l %%l in (1,1,%retries_limit%) do (
        set "flag="
        if exist "\\%%G\share\Tools\test1.txt" (
            set "flag=1"
        )
        timeout /T 1
    )
    if defined flag echo %%G is ok else echo something wrong with %%G
    @echo %time% end of %%G testing
)
endlocal
```

~

```
@echo off

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

FOR %%F "usebackq delims=" IN ("serverlist.txt") DO (
    echo testing %%G
    @echo %time% 
    for /l %%l in (1,1,%retries_limit%) do (
        set "flag="
        if exist "\\%%G\share\Tools\test1.txt" (
            set "flag=1"
        )
        timeout /T 1
    )
    if defined flag echo %%G is ok else echo something wrong with %%G
    @echo %time% end of %%G testing
)
endlocal
:checker
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    set retries_limit=10
    @echo %time% 
    for /l %%l in (1,1,%retries_limit%) do (
        set "flag="
        if exist "\\%~1\share\Tools\test1.txt" (
            set "flag=1" & goto :break_loop
        )
        timeout /T 1
    )
    :break_loop
    if defined flag echo %%G is ok else echo something wrong with %%G
    @echo %time% end of %%G testing
    endlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    (for %%s in (s1 s2 s3) do (
        pushd \\%%s\share\Tools 2> nul
        if errorlevel 1 (
            echo !time! %%s can not be accessed
        ) else (
            if exist test1.txt (
                echo !time! %%s hold key file
            ) else (
                echo !time! %%s does not hold key file
            )
            popd
        )
    )) > report.txt
```